# Groovy - how to delay Groovlet modification recompile check

Tags: servlets, groovy, web.xml

I am new to Groovy, and I am thinking about using Groovlets (not GRAILS) to replace some Servlets.  If I change a Groovlet's script file, the Groovlet re-compiles and automatically picks up the changes, including scripts referenced from the Groovlet.

This is great for development, but I imagine that groovy must perform lots of file checks to see if any of the scripts have been modified, not just on the main Groovlet, but on all referenced sub-scripts.  In a production environment, I imagine this could be lots of IO on every request.

I suppose there is a way to either disable having a Groovlet check to see if scripts have been modified, or perhaps there is a type of "update delay" like FreeMarker's setTemplateUpdateDelay() which only checks for modifications after N elapsed seconds/milliseconds since the last check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done in [GroovyScriptEngine](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/util/GroovyScriptEngine.java). It checkes for the last modification date of the source file, and if it's newer than the compiled version, it will recompile.

You can set the `minimumRecompilationInterval` in [CompilerConfiguration](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilerConfiguration.java). If you set that to a very high value, the [checking of the source](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/util/GroovyScriptEngine.java#L638) file won't be done that often.

Comment: This sounds promising.  Can you set this as a configure for groovlet.  Perhaps in web.xml

Comment: I don't see an obvious way to access the ComilerConfiguation within a Groovlet or when deploying it.  Any thoughts?