# Groovy script reloading on runtime

Tags: java, groovy, runtime

I want to be a able to execute a groovy script from my Java application.
I want to reload the groovy script on runtime if needed. According to their [tutorials](http://groovy-lang.org/integrating.html), I can do something like that :

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    try {
        GroovyScriptEngine groovyScriptEngine = new GroovyScriptEngine("");                
        System.out.println(groovyScriptEngine.run("myScript.groovy", new Binding()););
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("time " + (end - now));//24 secs
```

myScript.groovy

```
"Hello-World"
```

This works fine and the script is reloaded everytime i change a line in myScript.groovy.

The problem is that this is not time efficient, what it does is parsing the script from the file every time.

Is there any other alternative ? E.g something smarter that checks if the script is already parsed and if it did not change since the last parse do not parse it again.

Comment: reload the script only if `file.lastModified()` is differ from previous parsing

Comment: i will give it a try, but i would prefer a solid solution and not a "hack" with file.lastModified()

Comment: file.lastModified() is also slow but it's better than parsing the script again and again.

Comment: @daggett also do you know what is the best way to load the script from an external resource? (E.g from http webservice)

Comment: `def script = GroovyShell.parse(URI); script.setBinding(...); script.run();` and it's not clear what you are measuring inside 100K loop... better to split parsing and running...

Comment: That's exactly what I am planning to do. But in your code how can I know that the script from uri is different from the one already parsed so I don't parse it again

Comment: The simplest way - compare script text before parsing. you could try to use  `HTTP OPTIONS` method to minimize inet traffic.

Comment: I will try that thank you

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113384/groovy-how-to-delay-groovlet-modification-recompile-check/34115536#34115536
For the http part: daggett is right imo. Perhaps you could use apache CachingHttpClient or manually trigger the reload instead of an automatic check.

Comment: Manually trigger a reload is fine for one script but for many different scripts in different webservices this is not good I think.It is not manageble. Thanks  for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<< edited due to comments >>

Like mentioned in one of the comments, separating parsing (which is slow) from execution (which is fast) is mandatory if you need performance.

For reactive reloading of the script source we can for example use the [java nio watch service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html):

```
import groovy.lang.*
import java.nio.file.*

def source = new File('script.groovy')
def shell  = new GroovyShell()
def script = shell.parse(source.text)

def watchService = FileSystems.default.newWatchService()
source.canonicalFile.parentFile.toPath().register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY)

boolean keepWatching = true 
Thread.start { 
  while (keepWatching) {
    def key = watchService.take()
    if (key.pollEvents()?.any { it.context() == source.toPath() }) {
      script = shell.parse(source.text)
      println "source reloaded..."
    }
    key.reset()
  }
}

def binding = new Binding()
def start = System.currentTimeMillis()
for (i=0; i<100; i++) {
  script.setBinding(binding)
  def result = script.run()
  println "script ran: $result"
  Thread.sleep(500)
} 
def delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
println "took ${delta}ms"

keepWatching = false
```

The above starts a separate watcher thread which uses the java watch service to monitor the parent directory for file modifications and reloads the script source when a modification is detected. This assumes java version 7 or later. The sleep is just there to make it easier to play around with the code and should naturally be removed if measuring performance.

Storing the string `System.currentTimeMillis()` in `script.groovy` and running the above code will leave it looping twice a second. Making modifications to `script.groovy` during the loop results in:

```
~> groovy solution.groovy 
script ran: 1557302307784
script ran: 1557302308316
script ran: 1557302308816
script ran: 1557302309317
script ran: 1557302309817
source reloaded...
script ran: 1557302310318
script ran: 1557302310819
script ran: 1557302310819
source reloaded...
```

where the `source reloaded...` lines are printed whenever a change was made to the source file.

I'm not sure about windows but I believe at least on linux that java uses the fsnotify system under the covers which should make the file monitoring part performant.

Should be noted that if we are really unlucky, the script variable will be reset by the watcher thread between the two lines:

```
  script.setBinding(binding)
  def result = script.run()
```

which would break the code as the reloaded script instance would not have the binding set. To fix this, we can for example use a lock:

```
import groovy.lang.*
import java.nio.file.*
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock

def source = new File('script.groovy')
def shell  = new GroovyShell()
def script = shell.parse(source.text)

def watchService = FileSystems.default.newWatchService()
source.canonicalFile.parentFile.toPath().register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY)

lock = new ReentrantLock()

boolean keepWatching = true 
Thread.start { 
  while (keepWatching) {
    def key = watchService.take()
    if (key.pollEvents()?.any { it.context() == source.toPath() }) {
      withLock { 
        script = shell.parse(source.text)
      }
      println "source reloaded..."
    }
    key.reset()
  }
}

def binding = new Binding()
def start = System.currentTimeMillis()
for (i=0; i<100; i++) {
  withLock { 
    script.setBinding(binding)
    def result = script.run()
    println "script ran: $result"
  }
  Thread.sleep(500)
} 
def delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
println "took ${delta}ms"

keepWatching = false

def withLock(Closure c) {
  def result
  lock.lock()
  try { 
    result = c()
  } finally { 
    lock.unlock()
  }
  result
}
```

which convolutes the code somewhat but keeps us safe against concurrency issues which tend to be hard to track down.

Comment: I know this is the key to performace..I want to find the best way to re-parse scripts when needed. I can only thing of two ways to do that. Re-parsing every X minutes or manually trigger the re-parse. Can you think of a better way, or do you have a tip to help me implement such functionality in a proper way?